# showing articles using category filter sql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I want to select articles containing certain category I'm using typeorm ( SQL )
let's imagine i have

```
articleTable: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'string'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'string'
    }
];

categoryTable: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'string'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'string'
    }
]

article_categories: [
    {
      categoryId: 1,
      articleId: 2
    },{
      categoryId: 1,
      articleId: 1
    },{
      categoryId: 2,
      articleId: 2
    }
]
```

so the question is I want to select all articles that have exactly category = [1,2] and more
that means if an article has only category 1 I don't want to select it.

using this query I'm getting results but its not exact match of ids but instead it returns articles that have id 1 and 2 separately

```
async filterData(filterArticleDto: FilterArticlesDto, categoryIds: number[]) {
const qb = this.createQueryBuilder('article');
qb.distinct(true);
if (categoryIds.length) {
  qb.innerJoin(
    'article.categories',
    'categories',
    `categories.category IN (:...ids)`,
    {
      ids: categoryIds,
    },
  );
  qb.leftJoinAndSelect('categories.category', 'catsData');
}
qb.take(filterArticleDto.limit);
return await qb.getMany();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

raw sql query

```
SELECT article.*
FROM articles AS article
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT count(DISTINCT category_id)
  FROM article_categories AS subcts
  WHERE subcts.article_id = article.id
   AND subcts.category_id IN (1,
                              2)
 HAVING count(DISTINCT category_id) = 2)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=86f8d3a8bdc9248a918a4c37d8da5ea0

OR

```
SELECT article.*
FROM articles AS article
INNER JOIN
(SELECT article_id,
      array_agg(category_id) AS cts
FROM article_categories
GROUP BY article_id) AS category ON article.id = category.article_id
WHERE ARRAY[1,
        2::integer] = category.cts
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fdde52c1d11d69b690f9fe9345272786

Comment: Careful with that array version.  Without ordering the array_agg, there's a change that cts could be ARRAY[2,1], which wouldn't match.  It might be better to use ARRAY[1,2] <@ category.cts, but that would also match ARRAY[1,2,3], for example.  However, your first query would also match in that case.